# How can I use linked local files in ms access over network?

Tags: database, ms-access, attachment

I've an access db that have linked pics and PDFs in tables(I'd aware of db size limitation,thus I'd linked them).when I run db on creators PC (me) it can load files in eg: `c:\files\file.PDF` because it's there. But when I share db to other users on network they can't see files because they Dont have `c:\files\file.PDF` on their machine.
How can I solve this which users can see attachments?

> I don't want share files and manually update their files

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use a network share rather than a file path when you set up the links.

Comment: Thanks, what else if I copy the project to another office to use them.that should have same network structure to open it up.anyway to link like excel (open files from current db path ) !

Comment: You are correct. Else, you could ask your  user where the files are when the app starts up, then reconnect all the tables based on the new file location. I usually do that with my Access apps, but it's a bit of work when you do it the first time. My strategy is to create a table that contains the names of all the tables/PDF/etc. that need to be linked: then I have VBA code to step through that table and create all the links.

Comment: Interesting.thanks.I wish I have such this sample db if you mind ... (Mostafa zarghami Email.com).BTW I changed my db structure to use hyperlink.in this way my problem is solved and can move db and file that get together in same place to another PC.thank you very much